# How do I export gallery images using dataflow profiles onto different columns or otherwise

Tags: magento-1.9, image, csv, export, dataflow

Hi I'm trying to do a dataflow profile in magento that has all the specs I need.

However I can't separate the images out onto different columns of the csv or by a different type of delimiter within the same column.
Any help with this would be so greatly appreciated.

Is there an extension/script/file anywhere out there that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

This extension is really useful to `import/export` product, it has also different type of `dataflow` profile which you can customize as well.

With this you can export `gallery` images in different column as well.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-bulk-product-import-export-with-tier-pricing-product-custom-options-configurable-products-bundle-products-grouped-products-downloadable.html

Comment: After downloading this extension Ive realised that it is impossible to just get the gallery field on its own. It seems to only allow me to get the whole csv with all the fields in the database for each product. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Free Product Data Exporter PHP Script for Magento](https://www.atensoftware.com/p187.php), which exports all the product data as a CSV file.

It is open-source and licensed under GPL, so if you know a little PHP, you can modify it to export only the fields you wish to export.

By default, the gallery images will be in the aten_additional_image_url field, as a comma-separated list.

If you need something more robust, with filtering, automated daily export, etc., you can try [Aten Software's data feed service for Magento](https://www.atensoftware.com), which has a free trial.